# Experience Builder Register page using Customer Account Portal template - Fails & cannot bypass custom validation on Contact creation

Tags: community, digital-experience, experience-builder-page, self-registration

Using the below Self-registration configuration that includes added fields using User fieldset to capture country and mobile, the contact trigger has a validation for the MailingCountrycode and throws an error

[image: Registration Page Configuration]

[image: Registration fields]

This is custom validation on the contact trigger but has the option to bypass based on the profile. But even after adding the 'Customer Account Portal' profile to the validation bypass configuration, the error continues to be thrown.

With the other Registration option using 'Configurable Self-Reg Page', there is no issue since there is the ability to 'Execute Registration As' an user which has the validation bypass profile. In this option, the country code is updated in the Self-Registration flow that is invoked once the user and contact are created.

[image: Configurable Self-Reg Page]

**Questions:**

1. What user/profile does the registration execute under with the Experience builder page configuration? Is there an option to override that user/profile?
2. Is the assignment of the profile in the registration configuration only used for the purpose of assigning license to the user? Will that not be used when creating the user/contact?
3. What is the option to have the MailingCountryCode populated (from the country code entered) when the contact for the user is created? is that to be custom code in the various Apex controllers that come with the product? Or using a contact trigger?

Please note that I am not proficient with Salesforce development (Apex, etc.) - primarily using configuration  including Flows for discovery work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The registration is executed as the Guest User that is created for the Experience Cloud site. If you have a bypass on the validation that is set up already then you should be able to include the Profile that is automatically created for your site, which will be something like [Name of Site] Profile.

Comment: Thank You Callum. That worked. In addition to adding the profile to the bypass, I also had to change Object Settings. Followed the instructions as per this link https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.networks_public_access.htm&type=5.

Comment: However, will need to figure out why I am getting Welcome emails for both of the Portals. Is that due to sharing the same profile cloned from the Customer Community User profile across both portals - 1 using Experience Builder registration and the other using the Configurable  Self-Reg page? For each Portal, should I set up separate profiles? 

For multi-variant testing using the 2 registration pages, can it be done using a single Portal?

Comment: @Sam you're correct that it's due to the shared profile. Welcome emails are sent when a user is granted access to a community (which can be via Profile or Permission Set), so the shared profile will be granting access to both. I would definitely recommend creating a separate profile for each.

Comment: Thank you. Will change that

Comment: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.networks_selfreg_best_practices.htm&type=5

3rd bullet:
Create a separate profile or permission set for each self-registration use case and site.